# JVM variables escape equals when running from command line

Tags: java, jvm, escaping, flags

When running a Java application such as

```
java -Dme.unroll.url=unroll.me?param=val -jar my.jar
```

Does the `=` in `param=val` need to be escaped? This has been surprisingly hard to Google as most of the results are for escaping Unix shell special values. `=` is not a special character in a shell so

```
-Dme.unroll.url='unroll.me?param=val'
```

will be exactly the same. Must `=` be escaped in this context, and if so how?

Comment: The `?` needs to be escaped so that the shell doesn't interpret it as a glob.

Comment: Have you gotten weird results when not escaping it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis about to run it...  I posted the question anyway since it may still be bad practice, even if it works on my attempt.

Comment: When I tried it with simple `name=value` on Mac, I didn't get any issues. I can't think of any reason why you would. I didn't have a `?` in it though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well the ? needs unix-level escaping, that I'm aware of. I can't find doc on this stuff either, which is another reason I posted here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most normative reference I could find is the [Oracle `java` man page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABDJJFI), which states

> -Dproperty=value
>
> Sets a system property value. The property variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The value variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If value is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example -Dfoo="foo bar").

As it mentions spaces but not `=`, I interpret that to mean no `=` escaping is required.  That's somewhat unsatisfying, so I decided to look at what OpenJDK does.  As the widely-used reference implementation, its behavior sets a *de facto* standard.

At least in OpenJDK/HotSpot 8, when parsing `-D` options, all characters after the first occurrence of `=` are considered part of the value, so later occurrences of `=` do not need to be (and should not be) escaped.  See [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l980), the relevant part of which is

```
bool Arguments::add_property(const char* prop) {
  const char* eq = strchr(prop, '=');
  char* key;
  // ns must be static--its address may be stored in a SystemProperty object.
  const static char ns[1] = {0};
  char* value = (char *)ns;

  size_t key_len = (eq == NULL) ? strlen(prop) : (eq - prop);
  key = AllocateHeap(key_len + 1, mtInternal);
  strncpy(key, prop, key_len);
  key[key_len] = '\0';

  if (eq != NULL) {
    size_t value_len = strlen(prop) - key_len - 1;
    value = AllocateHeap(value_len + 1, mtInternal);
    strncpy(value, &prop[key_len + 1], value_len + 1);
  }
```

The call to `strchr` finds the first `=`, which is taken to be the divider between key and value.

Other bits of the code look for specific property arguments earlier in the VM start-up process, but all of the places I found did not perform any special handling of `=`.  For example, [the Java launcher](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/bin/java.c) both sets and checks some property arguments but does not escape or unescape `=`.